# How to find minimal value in array using multithreading in Python

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading

So I have array like this:

```
matrix = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]]
```

and I want the code to return 1 as It's a minimal value in this array. I know how to do it the simple way, but I have a hard time when I want to use mutlithreading. I tried this way:

```
import threading
matrix = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]]
def min(n, **total):
    if matrix[n][0] <= matrix[n][1]:
        minThreads['minThreads'] = matrix[n][0]
    else:
        minThreads['minThreads'] = matrix[n][1]

minThreads = {"minThreads":0}
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    t = threading.Thread(target=min, args=(i,), kwargs=minThreads)
    t.start()
print(minThreads['minThreads'])
```

But it returns 5 instead of 1. Do you maybe have any ideas how to implement this ? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can split the list in number-of-threads-used parts, pass each part to each thread, let them find the min value of each of their given lists and append that to some global list, wait for them to finish, then get the min value from that list.

Comment: The problem is that I need to use only multithreading for getting the result.

Comment: the issue is that you check each sublist and change the value in the dictionary based on the value that is smallest in that sublist not in the whole list, you want to add a condition that checks if the value in the dictionary is larger than the value you are looking at

Comment: Yes you always overwrite `minThreads['minThreads']`. You are always going to get the lesser value of the last checked row in your matrix.

Comment: Ok. I think I get the problem, but I have no clue how to solve It.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you write the lowest value of a row regardless it's value. in your case, last line run last, see 5 < 6, => writes 5 over the 3 that was written over the 1.
you should add comparison to the min value.

```
    import threading
    matrix = [[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]]
    def min(n, **total):
        if matrix[n][0] <= matrix[n][1]:
            if(matrix[n][0]<minThreads['minThreads']):
                minThreads['minThreads'] = matrix[n][0]
        else:
            if(matrix[n][1]<minThreads['minThreads']):
                minThreads['minThreads'] = matrix[n][1]
    
    minThreads = {"minThreads":matrix[0][0]}
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        t = threading.Thread(target=min, args=(i,), kwargs=minThreads)
        print('thread ',i)
        t.start()
    print(minThreads['minThreads'])
```

Comment: Ok. I see now how It works. Thanks!